# Python-calculate the highest tf-idf value of the first 100 words cross different tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tf-idf, tweets

I have collected thousands of tweets from twitter and I saved these tweets in one .txt file. Now,I want to calculate the tf-idf values of each word in tweets from this .txt file and extract the highest tf-idf value of the first 100 words.

**problems**

I can calculate each word's tf-idf value by Python’s `scikit-learn TfidfVectorize`,but each word's tf-idf value only represents the word's importance of the tweet it belongs to. I can not calculate out the highest tf-idf value through all tweets,but only every tweets's highest value words.

So my problem is that I can't compare word's tf-idf value belongs to different tweets.How can I calculate each word's tfidf values cross different tweets and extract the highest values of the first 100 words.

Comment: You correctly understood that tf-idf works when you have many documents (or tweets in your case); that's the idf part. So there is no such thing as 'each word's tfidf values across all tweets', there is 'each word's tfidf values for each tweet'. Regarding the whole twitter data, you could get the most common words (tf part) or just the 100 words with the highest tf-idf value - which will represent the word's importance of the tweet it belongs to.